# Group ArrayList of Custom Objects by Property

Tags: powershell

I would like to group `$mya`'s objects based on bytes:

```
Name           Bytes
----           -----
.\filedata.py  {105, 109, 112, 111...}
.\testfile.txt {100, 102, 115, 97...}
.\copyfile.txt {100, 102, 115, 97...}
```

I've tried

```
$mya | Group-Object -Property Bytes
```

But the result I get is strange:

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    3 {105, 109, 112, 111, 1... {@{Name=.\filedata.py; Bytes=System.Object[]}, @{Name=.\testfile.txt; Byte...
```

I don't understand why I got this result. I would have thought that the pipeline unwrapped all objects from `$mya` and grouped them based on their requested property, `Bytes`.

My desired outcome is:

```
Count Name                        Group
----- ----                        -----
    1 {105, 109, 112, 111, ...}   {\.filedata.py}
    2 {100, 102, 115, 97, ...}    {\.testfile.txt, .\copyfile.txt}
```

Comment: Group on all the bytes *displayed* (which depends on how much space is left for the column) or all the bytes the file actually contains (which is quiet a lot, and it would make more sense to group on [filehash](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash))

Comment: @iRon I can't filehash the actual files because they're hundreds of GBs in size. I'm taking the first hundreds of bytes in the file and comparing those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Group-Object` can't quite figure out what to do with your byte array values.

Use an anonymous property expression to create something `Group-Object` can meaningfully compare - like *strings* - from the byte arrays:

```
$mya | Group-Object -Property { [BitConverter]::ToString($_.Bytes) }
```

Comment: I just did that! Beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 0):

As @MathiasR.Jessen posted above, Group-Object reads the Bytes as being similar:

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    1 .\filedata.py             {@{Name=.\filedata.py; Bytes=System.Object[]}}
    1 .\testfile.txt            {@{Name=.\testfile.txt; Bytes=System.Object[]}}
    1 .\copyfile.txt            {@{Name=.\copyfile.txt; Bytes=System.Object[]}}
```

Under `Group`, the names are different, but the Bytes appear to be the same.
Convert the `Bytes` `ArrayList` into a `String`:

```
PS > $mya = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@{}
PS > foreach($file in $listofFiles) {$result = ($file | Get-Item | Get-Content -Encoding Byte -TotalCount 10) -Join ""; $mco = [PSCustomObject]@{Name=$file;Bytes=$result};$mya.Add($mco)}
0
1
2
PS > $mya

Name           Bytes
----           -----
.\filedata.py  1051091121111141163211297110
.\testfile.txt 100102115973210011810297115
.\copyfile.txt 100102115973210011810297115


PS > $mya | Group-Object -Property Bytes

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    1 1051091121111141163211... {@{Name=.\filedata.py; Bytes=1051091121111141163211297110}}
    2 1001021159732100118102... {@{Name=.\testfile.txt; Bytes=100102115973210011810297115}, @{Name=.\copyf...
```

Comment: Beware this variable-length encoding will cause collissions - string resulting from a byte array with decimal values 11 and 9 will be indistinguishable from one with 1 and 19 :)

Comment: I would be well-advised to use a space delimiter. That is an amazing attention to detail @MathiasR.Jessen